# Symfony - Add and persist extra fields

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a ChoiceType::Type field that display some choices, and i want to add, for each choices, an input to add a price on it. I did it like this :

```
->add('product_price', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array(
       "Product 1",
       "Product 2",
    ),
)
```

The JS that add the input for each choices :

```
var productBoxes = $("[id^=product_]");
// Listen the checkbox to display or hide the prices inputs
productBoxes.each(function (index) {
    var priceField = '<label class="control-label required" for="product_price_' + index + '">Capacité</label>' +
        '<input type="text" id="product_price_' + index + '"  name="product[price][]" class="form-control">';
    $(this).click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().append(priceField);
        } 
    })
})
```

The javascript works, it append fields next to each choices. Now I want to send my data in an array, like this :
["Product 1" => "value of the attached field"]

But I don't know how to fetch that extra data and save it to the database.

Did someone knows how to do it ?

**EDIT 1**
I tried to do it with CollectionType, but don't find out how to render each CollectionType element as checkbox. Is there a way to do it this way ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better way is to create custom type and set additional field there.

For example:

You main form type:

```
$builder->add('product_price', CollectionType::class, array(
    'label' => 'Prices',
    'entry_type'    => ProductPriceType::class
));
```

And ProductPriceType:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('product', TextType::class, array())
        ->add('price', NumericType::class, array());
}


/**
 * @param OptionsResolver @resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SomeEntity'
    ));
}
```

I think you get product data from base.
In this case you get array that contains 2 values - product and price

Comment: Yup, I tried like that, but not find out how to 1. Render CollectionType as checkboxes. 2. Append the price input on the product select. Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: You can add checkbox field in ProductPriceType. It will looks like checkbox for each product entry. And then save array item which has checked checkbox

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the easiest way would be to add two more fields to your form. Keep them hidden with CSS (display: none), and just show them with JS (toggle class "hidden" when the choice gets un/selected)

```
->add('product_one_price', NumberType::class, array(
    'attr' => array('class' => 'hidden')
))
->add('product_two_price', NumberType::class, array(
    'attr' => array('class' => 'hidden')
))
```

An alternative would be to have nested forms, or to build the form dynamically which may or may not be overkill, depending on what you're actually doing

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But in this way I need 1 field per product, and 1 field per price in my table. I do not want that. Nested form are a solution, but i really 1 checkbox per Product, and 1 field per checkbox..! Is it possible to do it this way with CollectionType ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I think you should dig in the ChoiceType class.

When using the basic ChoiceType, Symfony docs says :

> The choices option is an array, where the array key is the item's label and the array value is the item's value

If I correctly understand your case, you want something very specific like this kind of choices :

```
$choices = [
     'item_label' => [
           'value' => 'item_value',
           'price' => 'item_price'
     ],
     'item_label2' => [
           'value' => 'item_value2',
           'price' => 'item_price2'
     ],
     ...
]
```

I can't tell you precisely which class to override but your best bet will be to take a look at :

- ChoiceListFactory class
- ChoiceList class (the ChoiceType uses the child class SimpleChoiceList)
- ChoiceToValuesTransformer

I have two questions :

- What is the data model to store the label and the price ?
- What is this list for ? If it's too complicated for you to dig in the Form components, maybe you should split your process in two steps :

  1. One form to define your prices for your product
  2. One form to select the products you are interested in